# How to cast an int's address to char pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Currently the below code gives me a warning when i try to compile it:

int z;
char *w;

w = &z;

How can i cast &z properly so that w stores the pointer to z's address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
w = (char*) &z;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that generally casting pointers in C is a bad idea. Sure, there are some times when it is the right thing to do, but we can't see exactly what you're doing here. In most cases there is a better, more portable way to do whatever it is which you are aiming at here.